# Object attribute access in Perl

Tags: class, perl, object, yaml

I want to create a Perl class and populate its attributes. The object attributes will be populated like from a yaml files like below.

```
$data = LoadFile("$mydir/$ARGV[$j]");
my $X= $data->{a}{b}{c};

package Person;
sub new {
   my $class = shift;
   my $self = {
   a=>shift;
};
   bless $self, $class;
   return $self;
}
my $p=Person->new();
```

I want to access the attributes like this. How can I do this?

```
$p->a($data->{a}{b}{c});
```

Comment: The data in your object is what should be in the hash reference `{ }` which is assigned to `$self`.  For example, you can have `{ id => $n }` and so "attribute" `id` would have the value which is in `$n` variable.  The attributes are normally set up in the "constructor", so in the code you show. The values are passed in  when the object is created (that `new` is just a sub with arguments in `@_`).  Then they are changed and read using methods which you write.  Why not read over an introduction, like [perlootut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut), or an overview from your favorite Perl source?

Comment: [shift](http://p3rl.org/shift)  just takes the first argument. In a constructor, it's the class name.

How do you want to populate the object? Object can have attributes, but it doesn't make sense for an object to have "variables".

Comment: It's better to ask a single question. If you ask more (How to create + Can someone explain), it's hard for people who can only answer one of them.

Comment: That's right choroba! I will change that. Thanks!

Comment: `$p->a($data->{a}{b}{c})` makes no sense. Do you mean `$p->a()->{a}{b}{c}`?

Comment: You're doing `$p->a` (not `Person->a`), so you obviously want an object attribute (not a class attribute).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$p->a($data->{a}{b}{c})` makes no sense. Do you mean `$p->a->{a}{b}{c}`?

```perl
package Person;

sub new {
   my ($class, $data) = @_;
   my $self = bless({}, $class);
   $self->{data} = $data;
   return $self;
}

sub data { $_[0]{data} }

1;
```

```perl
my $data = LoadFile(...);
my $p = Person->new($data);
say $p->data->{a}{b}{c};
```